# Не получается открыть .mdb на linux python

Tags: python, linux, odbc, mdb

Имеется база данных в файле .mdb, необходимо её открыть в python в linux. Использую pypyodbc. Скачаны библиотеки unixodbc unixodbc-dev

```
import pypyodbc

conn = pypyodbc.connect('Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=/home/maxim/db.mdb;Uid=Admin;',
                        readonly=True)
print('connected')
conn.close()
```

После запуска этого кода, возникает ошибка

```
  raise OperationalError(state,err_text)
pypyodbc.OperationalError: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)' : file not found")
```

Помогите решить данную проблему

Comment: А вы это в Windows делаете? Если нет, то откуда по-вашему возьмётся парсер для ODBC? Вам надо конвертор, наверное, искать.

Comment: unixodbc и unixodbc-dev не то?

Answer (score 1):

ODBC это только протокол, к нему нужен ещё драйвер.

Драйвер от майкрософт поставляется при установке Access. Он тут не заработает.

Драйвер для линуксов в пакете [odbc-mdbtools](https://packages.debian.org/buster/odbc-mdbtools)

Нужно описать его в `odbcinst.ini`

```
[MDBTools]
Description     = MDBTools Driver
Driver          = libmdbodbc.so
Setup           = libmdbodbc.so
FileUsage       = 1
UsageCount      = 1
```

Теперь можно работать *(проверьте параметры подключения, давно не работал с аксесом - может что поправить надо)*:

```
pypyodbc.connect('Driver={MDBTools};Database=/home/maxim/db.mdb;Charset=CP1251')
```

Но работать с этим будет не легко и возможны какие-то несовместимости. Конвертируйте через mdb-export в csv и загрузите данные в sqlite.